# Is there an established way to use Django authentication with saml in a python3 environment?

Tags: django, python-3.x, saml

I would like to use the built in Django authentication with saml in a python3.4 environment

I tried pip installing djangosaml2 in a python3.4 virtualenv and encountered a series of python2.7 dependancies e.g djangosaml2 --> pysaml --> memchached --> mechanize --> twisted

I figured I would port the code from python2 to python3 and manually install it.

After 4 hours I decided it was too time consuming when I realized that the twisted API has changed considerably.